# sed find/replace lines with whitespaces

Tags: shell, sed

I'm writing a shell script that will find and replace a line to disable password caching in nscd.  The problem is, there is a ton of white space before and inbetween the parameters and I can't seem to find a way with my limited knowledge of regex to ignore the spaces and change the no to yes.

Here is the line as it appears in the config file.  Just in case it doesn't show properly, there are 8 spaces before enable-cache, 12 spaces after and 10 spaces before no.

```
    enable-cache            passwd          no
```

I basically need to change the no to a yes for that line only.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks

greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a complete usage example (albeit with input given on the command-line rather than from a file):

```
$ sed -r -e \
     's/^([[:space:]]*enable-cache[[:space:]]+passwd[[:space:]]+)no([[:space:]]*)$/\1yes\2/' \
     <input-file >output-file \
     && mv output-file input-file
```

To do this in-place, you'd want to use `ed` or `ex` (both, unlike `sed -i`, being POSIX-specified tools):

```
$ printf '%s\n' \
     '%s/\([[:space:]]*enable-cache[[:space:]]\+passwd[[:space:]]\+\)no[[:space:]]*/\1yes/' \
     'wq' \
    | ex file-to-modify -s -
```

Comment: Use `sed -i (...) file` instead of `mv`

Comment: @yoones Negative. `sed -i` is not POSIX compliant. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/sed.html

Comment: @yoones ...if you wanted a POSIX-compliant tool for edit-in-place, that would be ex or ed, not sed.

Comment: Your sed command worked in Linux but in Solaris, it returns saying the command is garbled.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1967720 As I specified, sed is the wrong tool for this job. Use `ex`.

Comment: @user1967720 ...by the way, while "garbled" isn't a good enough description to go from, I suspect that `sed -r` probably isn't available in Solaris, meaning that the regex would need to be rewritten to be a pure basic RE rather than an extended re (ERE). Again, though, using `ex` moots this.

Answer (score 0):

Match and capture the part starting from `enable-cache`, up to `no`, and also match `no`. Replace all matched part with the captured part and `yes`:

```
sed 's/\(enable-cache[ ]*passwd[ ]*\)no/\1yes/' input
```

Comment: Given as the original file is allowed to use tabs rather than spaces (specified as "whitespace" in the question, and given out-of-band knowledge that nscd's config file doesn't pick bones), writing code assuming only space characters seems a bit risky.